# addind text with itext7

Tags: c#, text, itext

I want to add text into every page of my pdf which is rotaded **from bottom to top**.
Like this: [image: this]
Here is my code:

```
        PdfDocument srcDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
        PdfDocument destDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(newfile));

        int pagesCount = srcDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
        {
            srcDocument.CopyPagesTo(i, i, destDocument);
            PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(srcDocument.GetPage(i));

        }
        srcDocument.Close();
        destDocument.Close();
```

In this I got stuck. I don't know how to go further : write and rotate text.

Comment: really quick, here's how you [rotate a paragraph](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-rotate-a-paragraph) and the [C# API call](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.12/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_style.html#a3996241c991ec73fbd5236c82455dbc7)

Comment: so, the idea is to add the rotated text to an already existing PDF document, right?

Comment: you also have some examples [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-adding-content-to-a-canvas-or-a-document) on how to add content to the canvas

Comment: @AndréLemos yes, on already existing PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as per the comments on the original question, you basically need to print on a [Canvas](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_canvas.html) object, and [rotate](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_style.html#a3996241c991ec73fbd5236c82455dbc7) the [Paragraph](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_element_1_1_paragraph.html). The [Rectangle](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_geom_1_1_rectangle.html#ade516ed1fe297db000247119ac73ad79) basically defines the coordinates where you will place the Canvas. Something like this should work:

```
PdfDocument srcDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
PdfDocument destDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(newfile));

FontProgram fontProgram =
    FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\temp\calibri.ttf");
PdfFont calibri = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI);


int pagesCount = srcDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
{
    srcDocument.CopyPagesTo(i, i, destDocument);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(destDocument.GetPage(i));
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, new Rectangle(36, 750, 100, 50));
    canvas.Add(new Paragraph("0001").SetRotationAngle(1.5708).SetFont(calibri).SetFontSize(4));
    canvas.Close();
}
srcDocument.Close();
destDocument.Close();
```

Alternatively, you can set a Style, if you plan on reusing a lot, something like:

```
Style rotatedStuff = new Style()
                .SetRotationAngle(1.5708)
                .SetFont(calibri)
                .SetFontSize(4);
```

and then just apply it to the [Paragraph](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_element_1_1_paragraph.html) with the [AddStyle()](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_element_1_1_abstract_element.html#a6682ab9c51fd43715fd40dd927e2013e) method.

Mind you that if you provide with a float number, it's in rads, so 90° is 1.5708 rad (1 Degree (°) = 0.01745 Radian (rad)).

Comment: Thanks dude! It helped me! One more question, how to change font ? eg. to Calibri and resize it to 4pt